# Run Node script promise through code and through terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, promise

Anyone got an idea on how to run a Node script that contains a promise as code, but at the same time make it available to use as a terminal command? I want the script to be part of a chain, but it should be executable by itself as well.

This should work (code sample):

```
var myFile = require('foobar')({
  file: 'index.html'
}).then(...);
```

and this as well (terminal sample):

```
$ node ./foobar.js --file=index.html
```

The contents of `foobar` contain a promise, something like:

```
// foobar.js
module.exports = function(opts) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // logic here
        resolve();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the following solution:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} args
 * @param {String} args.file
 */
module.exports = function(args) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //
    });
};

// Check if the second process.argv item is this filename. If so, we 
// know it has been called using `$ node ./foobar.js`
if (process.argv[1] === __filename) {
    // Execute the `module.exports` with the process.argv as an object,
    // converted by `minimist` module.
    module.exports(require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2)));
}
```

This way, I can call the script like:

`require('foobar.js')({file: 'myfile.html'})`

but also as:

`$ node ./foobar.js --file=myfile.html`